# Why canvas change all photos?

Tags: canvas, save

Доброго времени суток. При создании загрузчика фото с возможностью минимального его редактирования в браузере, столкнулся с проблемой, что при нажатии на кнопку `save` все изображения, которые я открывал в канвасе, из `FileReader` меняются на то 1 сохраненное. Может кто подскажет, что я делаю не так? https://jsfiddle.net/Lkf3thkt/

```
$droppedFiles.on('click', 'a[id^=change]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    let index = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]
    let IMG = this.previousElementSibling
    let naturalWidth = IMG.naturalWidth
    let naturalHeight = IMG.naturalHeight
    let lineWidth

    modal.style.display = 'block'
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    canvas.setAttribute('width', naturalWidth)
    canvas.setAttribute('height', naturalHeight)

    let img = new Image()
    img.src = `${IMG.getAttribute('src')}`
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, naturalWidth, naturalHeight)
    let isDrawing = false

    canvas.onmousedown = startDrawing
    canvas.onmouseup = stopDrawing
    canvas.onmouseout = stopDrawing
    canvas.onmousemove = draw

    function startDrawing (e) {
      lineWidth = $('input[type=range]').val()
      isDrawing = true
      context.beginPath()
      context.moveTo(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset + modal.scrollTop)
    }

    function draw (e) {
      if (isDrawing === true) {
        let x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft
        let y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop - window.pageYOffset + modal.scrollTop
        context.lineWidth = lineWidth
        context.lineTo(x, y)
        context.stroke()
      }
    }

    function stopDrawing () {
      isDrawing = false
    }

    $('#save').on('click', () => {
      dataURL = canvas.toDataURL()
      IMG.setAttribute('src', `${dataURL}`)
      dataArray[index].value = dataURL
      console.log('save div' ,IMG)


    })
    $('#clear').on('click', () => {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
    })

    span.onclick = function () {
      modal.style.display = 'none'
      // can.remove()

    }
    window.onclick = function (event) {
      if (event.target === modal) {
        modal.style.display = 'none'
        // can.remove()
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: Ссылка на полный код загрузчика

https://jsfiddle.net/Lkf3thkt/

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что "click" байндится на каждом вызове. от этого необходимо было сделать unbind клика по кнопке  ""save".

```
  $('#save').unbind("click").on('click', (e) => {
    let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL()
    $droppedFiles.find('#image-' +index ).attr('src', `${dataURL}`)
    dataArray[index].value = dataURL
  })
```